# XCode, display text with timer when an image is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to app developing and Xcode and I'm trying to make an iPhone app. I just wanted to ask, how do I make text appear (or other smaller images) for a certain period of time when an image is touched on the screen? couldn't find anything online any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out Swift gesture recognizers and timers. That'll lead you there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

in your `viewDidLoad`

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true     
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addText))
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

and add these functions

```
func addText() {
        // Display Text
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(removeText), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func removeText() {
        // remove Text
    }
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for @Nicholas.  This will also work for all GestureRecognizers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tap gesturerecognizer on image review below code for that.

> var imageView = <# imageView #> 
>      let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, > action:#selector(imageTapped(img:)))
>      imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
>     imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

For tap event :

> func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
>   {
>      // Your action 
>   }

Schedule Timer like this :

> myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, >selector: "updateTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

the timer passes itself to the selected method, so you can invalidate it inside the method if you need:

> func updateTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
>     Hide text or any obejct
>      timer.invalidate()
>   }